# How can i render a new page from footer menu in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try it with react router, but somehow it wont load it. I want to click on a link in the footer and should render the right page with footer and header. Somehow i dont get it to work, i read the react router documentation and follow the steps, but it didnt work for my case :/

My App.js

```
  function App() {
      <>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Banner />
        <Material />
        <Product />
        <Final />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/imprint" component={Imprint} />
        </Switch> 
        </Router>
      </>
```

In the footer named Final i call the link from react router

```
<motion.div
   ref={ref}
            initial={{ color: "#000" }}
            animate={{ color: inView ? "#000":"#fffffd" }}
            transition={{
              duration: 2,
            }}
            className='footer'>
            <p className='footerContent'>© {today.getFullYear()} KANI Ltd. All rights reserved.</p>
            <Link to="/imprint">
              <p classname='impressum'>Imprint</p>
            </Link>
            <ul classname='iconList'>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img className='insta' src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/instagram.png`}></img>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </motion.div>
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

To describe my problem a bit more:

If i click the imprint link it should render the app like this:

```
<Header />
<Imprint />
<Footer />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I can see, you have the switch only applying to the "Imprint" component. What you need to do is have the switch apply to all the components you want to literally *switch* in and out. You can also add a   `<BrowserRouter>`. So for example, you could re-structure your app page to look like this:

```
  function App() {
      <>
       <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/banner">
          <Banner />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/material">
          <Material />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/product">
          <Product />
         </Route>
         <Route exact path="/imprint">
          <Imprint />
         </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Final />
       </BrowserRouter>
      </>
```

This way whatever is contained within the `<Switch> </Switch>` will swap in and out, and everything outside of it, such as the header and `<Final>` will remain within the layout on every page.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i will try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 different paths like this:

```html
 function App() {
      <Router> 
        <Header />        

        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/imprint" exact component={Imprint} />
        </Switch> 
        
        <Footer/>
        </Router>
 }
```

and in Home put other components (Banner,Material, Product,Final) in  it

Comment: thank you, i had a similar idea, let me try it. Thank you for your answer